# Ubuntu Lags on Large File Deletion or transfer

Tags: 19.10

I am using an Ubuntu 19.10 PC w/ an i5 7th gen core CPU, 8GB RAM, and an SSD, but see much file handling delay.

It lags when I try to delete just 10 files,  10 KB each, which takes nearly 2-3 minutes to delete them, and I am unable to do anything for that time period, other that moving mouse. If I click on anything, the keyboard is no longer recognized during that delay.

So How can I enable Background Processesing of those files ??

[image]

Comment: 1) Did you check the downloaded ISO for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .?  2) When you boot from the LiveUSB instead of the installed system do you sill experience the slowness? 3) When booted from your internal disk, you run _ioping_ are the response times greater than 1 millisecond? 4) Please run _iotop_. copy the resulting tect, then return here, click [edit] and add the results to your question.

Comment: What brand/model SSD? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `df`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema i have added the Sreenshots now can you please help me with that ??

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for this kind of data. Copy/paste the text as an edit to your question. Thanks! You didn't say what brand SSD. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that's just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set **vm.swappiness=1** which is **TOTALLY** incorrect, especially with only 8G RAM.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 8G RAM and 2G SWAP), this way... (depending on your usage pattern, we may try 80 later)...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`